# Does $J_m(x) = i^m $ for some $x$?

Tags: bessel-functions

For integral $m$, we have

$$J_m(x) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{j!\ \Gamma(j+m+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2j+m}  = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{j!(j+m)!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2j+m}$$

I'm curious if $J_m(x) = i^m$ for some limit of $x$.

If we send $x\to 2i$, for example, we get

$$J_m(2i) = i^m\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{j!(j+m)!}$$

which doesn't quite do it.

Comment: Plug the value $x$ that does this into the recurrence, and see what it is...  Here is the recurrence: $$J_{n-1}(x)+J_{n+1}(x) = \frac{2n}{x}\;J_n(x)$$